# JavaScript's classes: toString() method

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there anything in the spec that defines a toString() method for classes?

For example, let's say I define this class:

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    console.log('hello');
  }
}
```

If I called `Foo.toString()`, I'm not sure if I'll get:

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    console.log('hello');
  }
}
```

Or perhaps the constructor function, anonymous:

```
function() {
  console.log('hello');
}
```

Or maybe the constructor function, but it's named:

```
function Foo() {
  console.log('hello');
}
```

Or maybe just the class name:

`Foo`

Comment: Have you tried running the code?

Comment: Have you tried reading the spec?

Comment: I've read the spec (https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-class-definitions) but there's nothing there about it. But maybe I didn't read it fully enough (toString might be defined elsewhere?), or maybe classes act like their underlying constructor function?



Running the code wouldn't matter if it's not in the spec, because I can theoretically create an ES6 runtime on my own that does whatever the heck I feel like when toString() is called on a class.

Comment: Re-read the spec and I found what Felix Kling is talking about. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually in ES6 "class" is just a function. So to understand how `toString` behave for so-called "classes" you must look at [toString() specification for function](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-function.prototype.tostring). It says:

> The string representation must have the syntax of a FunctionDeclaration FunctionExpression, GeneratorDeclaration, GeneratorExpession, ClassDeclaration, ClassExpression, ArrowFunction, MethodDefinition, or GeneratorMethod depending upon the actual characteristics of the object.

So for example 'toString()' for the next class:

```js
class Foo {
    // some very important constructor
    constructor() {
       // body
    }

    /**
     * Getting some name
     */
    getName() {
    }
}
```

`toString()` method will return string:

```js
Foo.toString() === `class Foo {
    // some very important constructor
    constructor() {
       // body
    }

    /**
     * Getting some name
     */
    getName() {
    }
}`;
```

**PS**

1. Pay attention that I wrote the string in back quotes ``` `` ```. I did it to specify multiline string.
2. Also spec says that `use and placement of white space, line terminators, and semicolons within the representation String is implementation-dependent`. But now all JS realizations remains them unchanged.
3. You can test example in Chrome Canary, which now supports ES6 classes.